# Running cron job creates an error unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: cron, cron-task

I can see that this is "usual" error, but can not find solution in my case...

Running Crontab job with:

```
expr `date +%W` % 2 > /dev/null && curl https://mysite.com/myscript
```

It causes errors:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can you help me how to avoid them? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 23):

You have to escape the `%` character. `man 5 crontab` says:

```
   Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless  escaped  with  backslash  (\),
   will be changed  into  newline  characters, and all data after the first %
   will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

Comment: This tiny piece of knowledge helped me enormously. I could not fathom why `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` worked perfectly in script but not in a (daisy chained crontab) command line. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 3):

Try to escape `%` AND don't use backticks to encose `date`-command. Do enclose it with `$()`:

```
expr $(date +\%W) % 2 > /dev/null && curl https://mysite.com/myscript
```

OR

```
expr $(date +\%W % 2) > /dev/null && curl https://mysite.com/myscript
```